# running a javascript with the help of VB inside of ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I want to know is there is way for running a javascript code with the help of vb

```
page:test1.aspx
<a href="#" onclick="Popup=window.open('testopen.aspx?jack=hello','Popup','toolbar=yes,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=420,height=400,left=430,top=23'); return false;">Test Window</a>
```

> page:test2.aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim check As String = "<a href='#' onclick='Popup=window.open('make_changes_form.aspx','Popup','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=420,height=400,left=430,top=23'); return false;>Test Window from vb</a>"
    Context.Response.Write(check)
End Sub
```

the code in `page test1.aspx` works
now i want to if there is a way for it to work in `page:test2.aspx.vb`because the current method  is not working for me.
Thank you

Edited
The reason im trying to do this is because i cannot use a function in javascript by passing as integer
for instance

```
Javascript
 function hello (str1)
  {
     alert(str1)
      alert ("hello world")    
   }

aspx code
    <input type="text" id="2">
    <a href="#" onClick="hello(2.value)">CheckFunction</a>
```

This is why i cannot use function because the function wont activate because id cannot be a number it has to have an alpha numeric value

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using Response.Write, you should really use a standard ASP.NET Hyperlink control and [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx). Then you could use jQuery to fire the alert:

On your page:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkPopup" ClientIDMode="Static" NavigateUrl="#">Show Popup</asp:HyperLink>
```

In your codebehind:

```
Dim js = <js>$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#lnkPopup').bind('click', function () {
        alert('Some text');
    });
});</js>.Value
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "jsPopup", js, true);
```

The actual script is a multiline literal which makes it easier to read in VB.NET.

Comment: Can you provide more details of the `<js>` block within VB.NET code? Never seen it before, and it looks useful.  In particular, which .NET version

Comment: It's a [multiline literal](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292152/Mutliline-String-Literals-in-VB-NET) which avoids messy code which is otherwise unavoidable in VB.NET due to lacking an @"" operator for literals. I missed a dollar sign out initially so I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Echilon i need to generate the link form the vb code because it comes form a database, that is why i used respone.write() to generate the link.

Comment: Coming from a database makes no difference to how you show the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Using Firebug, i noticed that the tag  wasn't comming with the javascript, so i created a function apart and called it from event onclick, it worked fine to me.

try this:

```
    Dim check As String = "<a href='#' onclick='OpenPopUp()'>Test Window from vb</a>"
    Context.Response.Write(check)
    jscript += "<script language='JavaScript'>"
    jscript += "function OpenPopUp() {"
    jscript += "window.open('popup_to_be_oppened.aspx', '', 'resizable=no , menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, width=290, height=480');"
    jscript += "} </script>"
    Context.Response.Write(jscript)
```

Also, you will have to use 
`hello(document.getElementById('2').value` instead of `hello(2.value)`

Comment: i need to create a list of link form database which opens in a new window, tried to modify it.Still doesnt work

Comment: which control do you use to open the new form? page_load?

Comment: try to take off that "; return false;" too

Comment: Check out my woknig code: jscript += "window.open('page_to_be_oppened.aspx?id=0&opener=cad_ind','','resizable=yes, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, width=800, height=500');"

Comment: Your code works fine.
currently im doing it on page load function. What i need to do is the link as i mentioned in the question should be generated automatically on pageload."Which it does" now all i want is to open that link in a new window. If you have trouble understanding my query in this comment let me know i will try to explain more appropriately

Comment: now let me know if i can pass id as integer into this function. Because this was the method i opted for previously but later on when i researched i found out that i could not pass id as integer. I had to pass it as string. Now since my id comes from a database i cannot do anything about it.

Comment: I think you can, i already did it btw, in your jscript: "window.open('your_popup_windown.aspx?id=3', '', 'resizable=no , [...] and in the load event of your popup : Dim id As Integer = Request.QueryString("id"). i actually use this, let me know if its not working for you

Comment: your method works like a charm, passing a value through url with help of ? and doing a Request.QueryString(). Please have a look at the edited part and try to to run the program like that. If it works do let me know

Comment: what about onClick="hello(document.getElementById('2').value)" ?

Comment: no, it didn't because i later found out that i needs to have a alphabetical value at the beginning of it then again i thought of appending one. But i didn't because of the hassle i would have to go through. Still, Thank you for trying to help